# Escape commas in c# for google microdata json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, escaping

Good Morning. I'm a front end developer without a c# knowledge, but i'm working on a website made with aspx 4.0.
I need to use the google ld/json microdata for the breadcrumbs of my website.
I had been able to print it into the html and that's the result.

```
result.Append(@" <script type='application/ld+json'>
{ '@context': 'http://schema.org',
'@type': 'BreadcrumbList',
'itemListElement': [{
'@type': 'ListItem',
'position': 1,
'item': {
'@id': '" + stringa + @"',
'name': 'Home'
}
},{
'@type': 'ListItem',
'position': 2,
'item': {
'@id': '" + stringa + @"',
'name': '" + stringa + @"' 
}
},{
'@type': 'ListItem',
'position': 3,
'item': {
'@id': '" + stringa + @"',
'name': '" + stringa + @"'
}
}]
}
</script>");
```

The html printed in the browser it is good but it fails the google test since it does not accept single commas. I tested it with double commas and it works. I tried to use the escape character \" but it does not work. How can i fix it? thanks

Comment: use double quotes: `""` like so: `""@context"":` but your life would be easier if you would just make the object structure you need and then serialize it to JSON.

Comment: Thanks man, it works!